# Bubble Sort 2D Array Alphabetically Java

Tags: java, bubble-sort

Could I get a second pair of eyes to tell me why my array is not being sorted every time it prints? I am attempting to sort a 2 x 3 array ( Student [][] classroom = new Student[2][3]; ) and alphabetize it by last name. My commented code is below:

```
//DECLARES THE CLASSROOM ARRAY 
  public static void sort(Student [][] array) {
      //In order for the loop to work, we must initialize values so that we can "Run" through the variables in our loop. 
      
      int a,b; //These are the variables used during loops. Type integer of positional spot needed. 
     
     
      //We will create a temporary Student called "temporary" 
      //This will host values when and if the "swap" occurs. 
      Student temporary = new Student();
      //The four loop initializing values; such as a, b will loop throughout each value of the area. 
      
      //The first two elements check the elements of the array. 
      //The last two loops run through the entirety of the array to run a compare check. 
      for (a = 0 ; a < 2 ; a++){
          
          for(b = 0 ; b < 3; b++) {
            if (b == 2 && a != 1) {
 
                if((array[a][b].getLastName().compareToIgnoreCase(array[a+1][0].getLastName()) > 0))
                temporary = array[a][b];
                array[a][b] = array[a+1][0];
                array[a+1][0] = temporary;
            }
            else if (b < 2) 
            {if((array[a][b].getLastName().compareToIgnoreCase(array[a][b+1].getLastName()) > 0)) 
                temporary = array[a][b];
                array[a][b] = array[a][b+1];
                array[a][b+1] = temporary;
            }
                
          }
          }//End-For B Loop
      }//End-For A Loop
  //End-Method Check
```

Comment: When posting questions like this, please include a minimal version of the class (in this case Student) and some test data.  Basically a [mre].  And you might want to explain the criteria governing that inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your code formatting! Always use {}.
If you don’t use the curved brackets only the next line depends on the if. So your code says:

```
  if((array[a][b].getLastName().compareToIgnoreCase(array[a+1][0].getLastName()) > 0)){
      temporary = array[a][b];
  }
  array[a][b] = array[a+1][0];
  array[a+1][0] = temporary;
```

What you probably wanted:

```
  if((array[a][b].getLastName().compareToIgnoreCase(array[a+1][0].getLastName()) > 0)){
      temporary = array[a][b];
      array[a][b] = array[a+1][0];
      array[a+1][0] = temporary;
  }
```

If you use Eclipse you can use `CTRL + SHIFT + F` to auto format.

Comment: Mentioning Eclipse is irrelevant to the problem.  You don't know what IDE the OP is using.  Nor would you know what the formatting preferences are set too or even desired.

Comment: @WJS You're right. But the code above has absolutely no system. And very likely that caused the problem. Beginners should get used to any formatting system and in Eclipse you could use this method. But of course I can't tell if the questioner is using this IDE.